# Null object reference on broadcast receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an activity that listens to a broadcast receiver like so:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing);

        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (action.equals("xxx.xxx")) {
                    boolean updateSuccessful = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("updateSuccess", false);
                    Log.i("HERE", String.valueOf(updateSuccessful));
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And in my Service, I am trying to broadcast a message that will be picked up by my activity. I do it like so:

private Intent intent = new Intent();

```
public void checkInternetConnection() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
                if (ipAddr.equals("")) {
                    connected = false;
                    isConnectedToInternet.postValue(false);
                } else {
                    connected = true;
                    isConnectedToInternet.postValue(true);
                    sendUnsentTagNumbers();
                }
               
                sendThisBroadcast();
                checkInternetConnection();
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                connected = false;
                isConnectedToInternet.postValue(false);
                checkInternetConnection();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                checkInternetConnection();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
}

private void senThisBroadcast() {
        intent.putExtra("updateSuccess", true);
        intent.setAction("autoswweep.att");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

How come when I get to the `sendBroadcast(intent)`, I get an error of:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at android.content.ContextWrapper.sendBroadcast(ContextWrapper.java:444)
        at sunmi.scan.services.CommonBoundService$6.run(CommonBoundService.java:199)
```

Comment: Might possible when your code is getting called your Service is already destroyed . Where exactly you are calling this code block ? add the code with question .

Comment: @ADM The broadcaster extends a service so I don't think it is already destroyed since I am doing the broadcasting inside it.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable about state of component Since its a scheduled code block .. You are basically scheduling it on every 3 seconds .  I'll Stick to my previous opinion i.e Your service is Destroyed That's the reason of NPE. You have to Check for your Service lifecycle . i can not make comment since i don't what kind of Service it is .

Comment: You're actually right about calling it every 3 seconds. I am thinking, as soon as I get it to work, I would place it somewhere it will not be called every n seconds. I use it on some other part of the code I just place it there so I can "visualize" it that it is being created so it won't have the NPE. But that's the thing though, since it was created, why is it now null? Please see my edit.

Comment: Creating `Intent` as global will not change anything its `sendBroadcast` method which throwing NPE because context is null probably. i can not say much right now  Add your Whole Service class with question . if it has large code then only add essentials code blocks. Also add how are you starting this Service .